# How to iterate through date time stamp and calculate no of hours in each day using python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a script to find the working hours recorded for a machine . The script loads different raw files generated by the machine and finally creates the data and time stamp column for a number of days.  Now I wanted to iterate through the date & time column and print the no of operating hours for each day.

```
import op
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

data=op.getting_files()
data= list(data)
l=len(data)
for i in tqdm(range(l)):
    f=data[i]
    df=pd.read_csv(f)
    df.head(500)
    df1=df[['Date','Time','TEMPPV','RHPV']]
    df2=df1.rename(columns={"TEMPPV": "Module Temperature", "RHPV": "Rel Humidity"})
    df3 = df2[(df2["Module Temperature"] > 83)& (df2["Module Temperature"] <87)]
    df4 =df2[(df2["Rel Humidity"] > 80)&(df2["Rel Humidity"] <90)]
   #df4 =df2[(df2["Rel Humidity"] > 83)& (df2["Rel Humidity"] <87)]]
    df4['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df4.pop('Date')) + pd.to_timedelta(df4.pop('Time'))
    op.append_df_to_excel('Dh summary.xlsx',df4,index=False)
```

after running the script the output look like this

Output[image: Output]

Now I would like to iterate through the entire Date Time column and calculate the operating hours for each day and print it.

The final file generated is available in the link below,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cpHhJJa6FF0rBSeEzv-7D5JoLmztOoLv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post a sample data in text?

Comment: @crayxt added file in the share link

Comment: I thought about a literal data snippet in your post, but anyways that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question here is how do you want to count operational hours?

To start with, we can group the dataframe per day and count the number of records for each day. That will give some picture.

```
>>> df.groupby(df.DateTime.dt.floor('d')).count()
            Module Temperature  Rel Humidity  DateTime
DateTime
2021-05-13                  18            18        18
2021-05-14                1391          1391      1391
2021-05-15                1440          1440      1440
2021-05-16                1440          1440      1440
2021-05-17                1396          1396      1396
```

If we check for `min`, `max` values, we can see that for dates if 14, 17 they are complete, but since in above table count is less than 1440 (24x6x60 = number of minutes in a day), there are some gaps in data. And we did not yet checked for possible duplicates.

```
>>> df.groupby(df.DateTime.dt.floor('d'))["DateTime"].agg([min, max])
                           min                 max
DateTime
2021-05-13 2021-05-13 04:29:00 2021-05-13 04:46:00
2021-05-14 2021-05-14 00:49:00 2021-05-14 23:59:00
2021-05-15 2021-05-15 00:00:00 2021-05-15 23:59:00
2021-05-16 2021-05-16 00:00:00 2021-05-16 23:59:00
2021-05-17 2021-05-17 00:00:00 2021-05-17 23:59:00
```

**Update:** Ok, since the data is at minute level, we can sort, drop duplicates and count number of records each day, which gives you time in minutes.

```
>>> df = df.sort_values(by="DateTime")
>>> df = df[~df.DateTime.duplicated()]
>>> df.groupby(df.DateTime.dt.floor('d'))["DateTime"].agg("count")
DateTime
2021-05-13      18
2021-05-14    1391
2021-05-15    1440
2021-05-16    1440
2021-05-17    1396
```

Comment: Actually, the data are not in a proper order. I mean, there are gaps between the data and time stamps. Some days, due to power failure, the data was not recorded. So to compute the total hours of operation, I need to go through each date and calculate the no of hours for that day and then add the total no of hours for the entire date and time. .